# "Items in your active configuration have changes"

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to setup configuration management for our team, so i test the workflow on my **local machine**:

Starting from a fresh copy of our website + database backup, with an empty /config folder ($settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config';). When i use the command "drush config:export", the task runs and all the .yml files are generated in the /config folder.
**I then change the websites name (system.site), just as a simple test**.

Then, when visiting the configuration management UI in drupal, i would expect to see only 1 change. And indeed that is the case but i also see a **huge list (all config)** of untouched settings and the warning "**The following items in your active configuration have changes since the last import that may be lost on the next import**"

If i just exported all my config, did 1 change, then why is it saying that i have changes in my db that don't match with .yml files in the /config folder?

However, if i first click on 'import all', do the 1 change, revisit the configuration management UI, then i also get the warning but only with the 1 change.

So why is that?

[image] [image]

Comment: Init git, track changes exactly. Probably just sorting. What happens when you re-export again, then change site name again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of [configuration sorting](https://www.drupal.org/node/3230199).